# Validate form being submitted using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

so this might be something super simple to do, but I can't seem to get it. I have a form and a validation for it. The validation text works. If I use a normal submit button the form works correctly, but if I use javascript to submit the form, it does not work 100%.

```
<form id="transport" name="transport" method="post" action="submit_trans_request.php">
    <input type="text" name="f_name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['f_name'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" style="font-size:16px;"  />
    <a href="javascript:onclick=validateForm(); document.transport.submit();" class="submit_btn">Submit</a>
```

So basically I am looking for a way to stop the submit if `validateForm()` returns an alert. Not sure how I go about that.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need `return false;`

Comment: Where do I put that?

Comment: Where you put your alert, inside the block where you have decided the form didn't validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it the way you've designed it by just `returning false` in the `validationForm()`.

If I were you, I would just call whatever method you want when the user clicks submit, then inside of that method, call the `validationForm()` method. If that returns `true`, go forward with the process, otherwise alert the user.

Something like this:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" />
   <a href="javascript:onclick=submitData();"/>
</form>
```

Then in the `submitData()` function, do something like this:

```
function submitData() {
    var b = validationForm();

    if (b) {
        // submit data
    } else {
        // alert user something entered wrong
    }
}
```

Now, in the `validationForm()` function, you need to make sure that you return `true` or `false`.

Comment: As I thought, I overthink things and make them more complex than they should be. I appreciate all the help! Thank you!